# Two fragments accessing the camera hardware in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a ViewPager with three fragments. For the last two fragments, I need to access the camera.

Now I cannot create two different fragments for the last two fragments as two fragments cannot access the same camera hardware at the same time.

So I just want that when I go from fragment 2 to 3 the slider for tab layout to move as usual but the fragment should be the same.

What possible solution should I go for? Is there a way I can play with view pager and tab layout to achieve this or I will have to create my own slider using animations?

Comment: No you shouldn't give illusion of fragment reuse. It seems like a bad UX where same feature is being accessed from different place. But still if you want to access Camera from two different fragments, then pause the camera in one and resume in other. `setUserVisibilityHint(boolean isVisible)` is the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I achieved this is by using view pager transformer. When I move from fragment two to fragment 3 I translate fragment in the opposite direction. So the tabs below change but the fragment remains the same.

Although I do change the camera sessions from video to picture when moving from fragment 2 to fragment 3 or vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

You must need release you camera in fragment 2 and connect again when you switch to fragment 3.